# SASS, animate each list items with a delay

Tags: css, sass, mixins

Looking for a nice mixin to have less code in my files. The animation is pretty simple, each list item when triggered will slide in from the left with a delay(per element). The 'transition' mixin is a basic transition(all vendors) mixin.

```
.nav-main{

     li:nth-of-type(1) a{             

       @include transition( 0.5s linear 0.5s);

     }

     li:nth-of-type(2) a{


       @include transition( 0.5s linear 0.6s);

     } 

     li:nth-of-type(3) a{


       @include transition( 0.5s linear 0.7s);

     }

     li:nth-of-type(4) a{


       @include transition( 0.5s linear 0.8s);

     }

     li:nth-of-type(5) a{


       @include transition( 0.5s linear 0.9s);

     }

// and so on...

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [for loop](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_10) to achieve this.

```
.nav-main{
  @for $i from 1 through 5 {
    li:nth-of-type(#{$i}) a {
      @include transition(0.5s linear (0.5s + ($i - 1) * 0.1s));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prepared mixin can be useful in other situations.

```
@mixin nthChildNav($item, $count) {
    $a-delay: 0.5s;
    $a-duration: 0.5s;

    @for $i from 1 through $count {
        #{$item}:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
            a {
                @include transition($a-delay linear ($a-duration + ($i - 1) * 0.1));
            }
        }
        // @debug $i;
    }
}

.nav-main {
    @include nthChildNav(li, 5);
}
```

Regards :)